DOM cannot see image from gallery Expo
I have problem on my expo app. I'm using react-mobile-cropper for image crop, but when Im sending image from gallery, it not shows up. why?
"expo": "^52.0.21",
"react": "18.3.1",
"react-mobile-cropper": "^0.10.0",
log:
LOG  file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20241208_213008.jpg



"use dom";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, ChangeEvent } from "react";
import { Cropper, CropperRef } from "react-mobile-cropper";
import "react-mobile-cropper/dist/style.css";

const CropperComp = ({
  image,
  onCrop,
}: {
  image: string;
  onCrop: () => void;
}) => {
  const cropperRef = useRef<CropperRef>();
  console.log(image);
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        userSelect: "none",
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          position: "relative",
        }}
      >
        <img src={image} style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }} />
        <Cropper
          ref={cropperRef}
          style={{
            maxWidth: "100%",
          }}
          src={image}
        />
      </div>
      <div>{image && <button onClick={onCrop}>Download result</button>}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CropperComp;




